# How can i develop a custom search for odoo

Tags: odoo

How can I develop a custom search function for odoo to work with POS as I will be listing ore than 5000 products so i need an effective search.

I know search in python RE is not effective but i wuld like to split the search to 2 like search "white" and "bread" seperate will first for bread, then white in those results. This is more effective, but it has to be from POS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not sql queries directly?

This can be done easily using a wizard. Set a list of search paramters in wizard and then a "search" function using sql.

Hope this idea helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about search views? If so, try Search section of this link:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html

Your task, as you described it, can be done via search views. I can do nothing more since you're not even seemed to provide some efforts.